# Bound of weighted trace of a self-adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be self-adjoint matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$. Suppose $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^n$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $c_1\geq c_2\geq\cdots \geq c_n$. Show that $$\sum_{j=1}^nc_j\lambda_{n-j+1}\leq\sum\limits_{j=1}^n c_j\langle Ae_j,e_j\rangle\leq\sum\limits_{j=1}^nc_j\lambda_j.$$

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3184420/81360) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3637453/81360).

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you.